# How to create the text file in temp directory of an app in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

please tell me how can i create a text file in temp directory of my app if it does not exists.

please guide me ,i m not going right way for this & trying for past 1 hour.

sorry friends but i m unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to handle any file operations Use NSFileManager. For your case

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path

- (BOOL)createFileAtPath:(NSString *)path contents:(NSData *)contents attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

If you want to know detail see the Documentaion

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html